# How to sort an array with the vales first and then the keys?

Tags: php, sorting

As the title says. For example:

Original

```
{18=>13, 0=>13, 27=>13, 9=>13, 19=>13, 12=>12, 21=>12, 31=>12, 4=>12, 22=>12}
```

I want it become like this:

```
{0=>13, 9=>13, 18=>13, 19=>13, 27=>13, 4=>12, 12=>12, 21=>12, 22=>12, 31=>12}
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you even search SO?... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874181/php-sort-an-array?rq=1   OR   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key?rq=1

Comment: I want the value in descending order and the key in ascending order.And I tried to second link, It doesn't work.@DarylGill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try

```
$array = array(array_values($array),array_keys($array));
array_multisort($array[0], SORT_DESC, $array[1], SORT_ASC);
$sorted_array = array_combine($array[1],$array[0]);
```

Comment: This one works, thanks so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

```
$array = //Your array value

asort($array);
ksort($array);
```

Comment: Then it becomes ascending in index, no use....

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at ksort

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

For example...

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
ksort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
  echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

**Output**

a = orange

b = banana

c = apple

d = lemon

Comment: -1: Does not take into account the values, which is the first sort criteria as specified by the OP.

Comment: I need the values in descending order and the keys in ascending order...